# Could not process incoming request - square connect SDK

Tags: sdk, square-connect

> Sorry, we could not process the incoming request. Please try again or contact support

I get this error when making a SDK payment request; I have double checked my application (client) id; I got the merchant ID by requesting the merchant profile; I have checked the ios bundle id and call back urls., cant seem to find a reason this wouldnt work (I am an approved partner).

```
square-commerce-v1://payment/create?data={"state":"Useful information","callback_url":"{{redacted}}","merchant_id":"{{redacted}}","amount_money":{"amount":100,"currency_code":"USD"},"options":{"clear_default_fees":true,"supported_tender_types":["CREDIT_CARD"]},"client_id":"{{redacted}}","sdk_version":"1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error is occurring because the provided value of the `data` parameter is not URL-escaped. If you URL-escape everything after `data=`, the request should succeed.

Comment: I went back and messed around with the bundle id, merchant id, app id, post back, etc... I noticed there was a similar question by someone who was trying to use it in a web-application and figured that if the only reason this would throw an error was if it was not an approved partner then something must have been connecting the request with the correct application id / merchant....  Long story short. after waiting for 30 minutes or so, it started working. seems like it takes some time to propagate changes